# Perl module 'WWW::Mechanize::Chrome' do not work

Tags: perl

I use'WWW::Mechanize::Chrome' to gen pdf.

```
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
use WWW::Mechanize::Chrome;
my $chrome;
sub chrome {
    Log::Log4perl->easy_init($ERROR);
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new(
    headless      =>  1,
    'disable-gpu' =>  1,
    launch_exe    =>  'chromium-browser',
);
```

When I call `new` I have got the error.If to look deeper, we can see the error while concatenation at 797 line. Why is this happening and what to do about it?
[image: the place where error happened]

[image: values of variables]

[image: error text]

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign to function:

Run this example and you will get same error on line 3:

```perl
sub test { }
sub left { }
left() .= test()
```

Particularly in this case your debugger can not process `lvalue subroutine`

Comment: The error is called by debugger